# Converting 2D images to 3D with MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, matlab

I want to convert a 2D picture to 3D with MATLAB.

I would be happy if you introduce me some books or codes or anything that may help me to that.

Comment: The search terms you're looking for are depth from shading, depth from defocus, depth from stereo, depth from motion (or structure from...). But this is still largely a research area, so don't expect ready-to-use libraries or code that works equally well on any kind of image.

Answer (score 7):

2D to 3D conversion is a broad topic with very limited solutions. Problems range from scene analysis to MRI scan reconstruction. Current algorithms may be coarsely divided into two categories depending on the input type: a single 2D image or multiple 2d images. Depending on the type of input, specific depth cues can be exploited, e.g.: binocular disparity, motion, defocus, etc.

- One of many books on the topic: "An Introduction to 3D Computer Vision Techniques and Algorithms" by Cyganek and Siebert.
- "Converting 2D to 3D: A Survey" by Q Wei, 2005. ([PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.2308&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).
- Matlab code to render a 3D array from 2D data such as MRI. ([vol3d.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4927)).
- Matlab tools for computer vision by Peter Kovesi. ([webpage](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/)).
- Non-matlab solutions: Avizo http://www.vsg3d.com/vsg_prod_avizo_overview.php
  Amira http://www.amiravis.com/
  VolView http://www.kitware.com/products/volview.html
  VolVis http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~vislab/volvis_home.html
  Vis5D http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~billh/vis5d.html

Answer (score 0):

The above post gives an excellent broad overview. Some cool applications, for a single 2D image to 3D are these, mostly based on monocular depth cues are and scene structure constraints are...

- Make3D: http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/
- Photo pop-up etc : http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/homes/dhoiem/projects/popup/